# How to encode binary image data for http response headers?

Tags: python, image, http, encoding, http-headers

I've been trying to respond to serve images when someone goes to a url like localhost:5000/image.png. I'm serving the headers via python sockets

Steps I tried:

1. When the file is requested, I first loaded the raw binaries of the file as shown below.

```py
   data=open(filename, "rb").read()
```

2. After loading the binaries, I formatted it into the headers as shown below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: {len(data)}

{data}
```

When I return the response, the browser displays a **small white box**.

[image: example]

After trying several solutions I found online(mentioned below btw), I concluded that the white box only appears if the data I'm returning in the response is invalid

Things I've tried:

- Encoding the data variable using base64 encode, same result
- Attempting to decode the data using utf-8, raises "Invalid Start Byte"
- Attempting to decode the data using ISO-8859-1, it did decode but it displays the same white box
- I've tried the same thing with non image files with their respective content-types, they work perfectly

**Source code of the part**

```py
class ClassicFileRequest(object):
    @staticmethod
    def create(response, rtp):
        basestring=f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: {rtp}\nContent-Length: {len(response)}\n\n{response}" # Base string, this is where all the file data is formatted
        return basestring

def responsefromfile(filename):
    print(filename)
    ft=mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    if filename.endswith((".webp",".jpeg",".png",".gif",".ico")):
        data=open(filename, "rb").read() # Read binaries for image files
        return ClassicFileRequest.create(data, ft)
    else:
        data=open(filename, "r").read()
        return ClassicFileRequest.create(data,ft)
```

**UPDATE:***

The error has been fixed, apparently formatting a bytes object into a string wasn't a great thing to do

Comment: Have you tried using just data.encode()?

Comment: the rb parameter returns a bytes object, it doesn't have an encode function

Comment: Sorry I meant decode(), if you insert a bytes object into string then there is a b before it.

Comment: i mentioned at the end of the question, decoding it raises an "Invalid Start Byte" error when using UTF-8. tried iso-8859-1 but thresult is the same as the screenshot i shared in the question

Comment: You really need to supply more information. Show us the source code. FWIW, binaries do not need to be encoded when sent over HTTP.

Comment: @JulianReschke I have added the source code into the question

Comment: Fixed: turns out the formatting bytes into a string wasn't a great idea